# Using std::vector to create a bunch of projectiles, how to make them appear one after another?

Tags: c++, sfml

All the code except for the for loop part works as intended and is just for your information.

I don't know how to by pressing 1 button release objects from the vector towards the mouse one after another, with each click  a different object, while not making the previous object dissapear. If I try to put all of them on 1 button they all spawn at the same time. This is the only thing i need help with. I'm sure there's a smart way to do this.

```
class Player
{
public:

sf::RectangleShape rect;

Player(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f size)
{
    rect.setPosition(position);
    rect.setSize(size);
}
```

...
 this is the projectile

```
Player crystalArrow(Player(sf::Vector2f(100,100), sf::Vector2f(30, 30)));
```

...  this is the vector /:

```
std::vector<Player> stars(5,crystalArrow);
```

...

```
float angle2 = atan2(mousePosition.y - bullet.y, mousePosition.x -  bullet.x);
```

...

```
for(int i = 0; i < stars.size(); i++)
{ 
     stars[i].rect.setTexture(&Astar);
     window.draw(stars[i].rect);


}

         if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
                  stars[0].rect.setPosition(300,300);
         if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
                  stars[1].rect.setPosition(300,300);
         if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
                  stars[2].rect.setPosition(300,300);
         if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::F))
                  stars[3].rect.setPosition(300,300);
         if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::G))
                  stars[4].rect.setPosition(300,300);
         stars[0].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
         stars[1].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
         stars[2].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
         stars[3].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
         stars[4].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
```

;-)

New code:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < stars.size(); i++)
     { 
     stars[i].rect.setTexture(&Astar);
     window.draw(stars[i].rect);


}

     if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A) && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 0.3f && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 0.35f)
             stars[0].rect.setPosition(Helif.rect.getPosition());
     if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A) && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 0.6f && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 0.65f)
              stars[1].rect.setPosition(Helif.rect.getPosition());
     if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A) && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 0.9f && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 0.95f)
              stars[2].rect.setPosition(Helif.rect.getPosition());
     if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A) && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 1.2f && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 1.25f)
              stars[3].rect.setPosition(Helif.rect.getPosition());
     if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A) && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 1.5f && clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 1.55f)
              stars[4].rect.setPosition(Helif.rect.getPosition());
     if(clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 1.56f)
         clock.restart();
     stars[0].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
     stars[1].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
     stars[2].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
     stars[3].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);
     stars[4].rect.move(cos(angle2)*10,sin(angle2)*10);`
```

and the direction(angle) is calculated every time button is pressed:

```
float angle2 = atan2(mousePosition.y - bullet.y, mousePosition.x -  bullet.x);
```

Comment: What is `std::vertex`? Do you mean `std::vector`?

Comment: Yes, I meant std::vector (title is changed now to corect) thanks for pointing this out ;)

Comment: So, what happens? When you press a key, the corresponding object is 'spawned' (i.e. reset to 300,300) and moved, but all other objects disappear?

Comment: add some timeout after reading from keyboard (a few milliseconds), to make it impossible to release all elements at once. Alternatively you can check whether key was "pressed and released" instead of only checking the "pressed" part

Comment: @Daerst when pressed key all objects are spawned together, I just mentioned dissapearing becouse I wanted to avoid it in responses (i want bullets to fly all the way until collision)

Comment: @TomaszLewowski I made progress in accord to your idea.(check main post) The bullets are now being released one after another like I wanted. New problem is all the bullets are going in the same direction, which is changed when new bullets are created. This causes the bullets to change their direction in mid-flight wchich looks so funny. What could I use to make every bullet keep their direction until they collide into something or they get restored to start location?

Comment: Basically, you need to associate angle (and possibly speed, if you want to introduce it later on) with a bullet, and not with a single variable. So, you'll need something like `std::vector<double> angles`, and at releasing bullet you'll need to push next value to this container, and move bullets according to their angle..